# unable to zip 1 GB file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a batch script that does the following tasks.
1. Create a backup folder
2. Zip specific files (text files in .log format) and move zipped files to backup folder
3. Delete the original files after moving

To accomplish the 2nd task, I'm writing the commands into VBScript file from batch script like below and then executing the VBScript at the end of batch script.

```
echo Option Explicit >> zipIt.vbs
REM remaining commands
CScript zipIt.vbs
```

The batch script successfully performs all 3 tasks for a file of size 100 MB.
But fails at VBScript command for file of size 1 GB. Following error is thrown at command prompt

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\zipIt.vbs(18, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error
: Permission denied
```

Below is the content of zipIt.vbs Written line numbers here for convenience.

```
1. Option Explicit 
2. Dim FileToZip, Result 
3. Dim oShell 
4. Dim file 
5. Dim oFileSys 
6. Dim winShell 
7. FileToZip = "C:\Program Files\logs\File_2013-04-29.log" 
8. Result = "C:\Program Files\logs\File_2013-04-29.log.zip" 
9. Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
10. Set oFileSys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
11. Set file = oFileSys.CreateTextFile(Result, True) 
12. file.Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0) 
13. file.Close 
14. Set file = nothing 
15. set winShell = createObject("shell.application") 
16. winShell.namespace(Result).CopyHere FileToZip 
17. wScript.Sleep(5000) 
18. oFileSys.DeleteFile FileToZip
```

Getting the same error if VBScript is run alone. Is it because of large file size?

Comment: VBScript is just creating an empty zip file i.e. `File_2013-04-29.log.zip` But it fails to add the .log file and delete the original file.

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely a problem with memory, seeing as applications are capped at a maximum of 2GB, within windows at least, it is most likely an issue of the program trying to access memory that it was not allocated.

Comment: Is there any way to overcome this limitation?

Comment: there is a way to extend it to 3GB but I am pretty sure that requires win32 api access. past that is impossible, due to operating system limitations.

Comment: My requirement is to have the zipping capability from VBScript for a file of size up to 1 GB. Is it possible by modifying the VBScript alone?

Comment: In theory you could modify the script to only run in small portions of the file at a time. that way you would be able to control how much memory is used.

Comment: I can't modify the script to implement the above logic, with my limited knowledge in VBScript.  How about adding more sleep time? For example, with `WScript.Sleep(10000)` the script worked fine for 200MB file size. Tried just now.

Comment: It is worth a shot but its probably a long shot.

Comment: How does the script as shown create a compressed ZIP file?  It seems to write the zip header to a file, append the log file - but how does it compress?

Comment: EDIT: Well I tested it and it works.  I'm not clued up in VBS it seems.

Comment: This could be a possible reason for Permission denied error:            The error occurred at line number 18, which has a command to delete the original log file.
But, the command at line number 16, which will add the original log file to an empty zip file was still using that file.
The sleep time at line number 17, was not enough for above task to be completed.

Comment: I was under the impression that the function was blocking? If not that would make much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution

Split large log files in little chunks:

```
BreakFile = "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\Test.txt"
limit = 400000 ' Bytes

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Breakfile, 1)

FiletoSplit = objFSO.GetFileName(BreakFile)
FolderDest = Mid(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(BreakFile),1,Len(objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(BreakFile))-(Len(FiletoSplit)))
FileSplitName = objFSO.GetBaseName(BreakFile)
dtmStart = Now()

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Breakfile, 1)
strContents = objFile.ReadAll
FileNum = 1
fname = FolderDest & FileSplitName & "Split " & FileNum & ".txt"
Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fname, 2, True)
CountLines = 0
arrLines = Split(strContents, vbCrLf)
HeaderText = arrLines(0)

For i = 0 to ubound(arrlines)
    strLine = arrLines(i) & vbCrLf
    objFile1.Write strLine
    If (Countlines) < limit Then
        countlines = countlines + 1
    ElseIf Countlines >= limit Then
        objFile1.Close
        Countlines = 0
        FileNum = FileNum + 1
        fname = FolderDest & FileSplitName & "Split " & FileNum & ".txt"
        Set objFile1 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(fname, 2, True)
        objFile1.Write HeaderText & vbCrLf
    End If
Next

objFile.Close
dtmEnd = Now()
```

Then Zip it all together, and when extract the content, use a "Copy /B" batch command like this to join the chunks:

```
Copy /B "MyLog_Part*" "MyLog_Complete.log"
```

Comment: I will try out your solution. But as of now, I will stick with whatever I mentioned earlier: Increasing the sleep time based on the size. Thanks a lot Elektro.